# Populating Tableview with static data

Tags: ios, mysql, uitableview, model, swift3

I am creating a tableview that populates with popular restaurants in a user's particular area and I wanted to know what the best practice would be in storing and retrieving this data. The data is static and will only change based on user's location, so due to this I think it would be best practice to create a model class where arrays have stored all the restaurant information, such as phone number, business hrs etc. However I am unsure if it should create a table in my MySQL database and update it there instead, any suggestions?

Comment: Depends upon the requirement.

Comment: do you mind elaborating?